# Facebook deep link notifications not opening iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm new to this FB deep linking and followed all the steps mentioned in the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/deep-linking/ However, when I send the test deeplink from FB Ads console, clicking on the Ads opens the app page on AppStore instead of opening my app. Please help.

expected results:- launch the app

I tried all the forums mentioned in the developer documentation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use this piece of code:

```
let svcWWW : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/radioNED/")!
let svcFB : NSURL = NSURL(string: "fb://profile/1238133072954301/")!
        
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(svcFB as URL)) {
            
    UIApplication.shared.open(svcFB as URL, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil)
            
} else {
            
    UIApplication.shared.open(svcWWW as URL, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil)
            
}
```

It opens the Facebook app if available. Otherwise it will open Safari en load the Facebook webpage.

I hope this helps you out ;)

Comment: this piece of code will be added in AppDelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function right

Comment: Actually, I will trigger Deeplink notification from FB developer portal to FB application. when I click on the notification it has to open the app where I have configured to support fb Deeplink, if the app is not installed It has to redirect to App Store. but now I will be redirected to App Store even if app is installed in my device

Comment: I use this for a "Facebook" button in my app.

Comment: UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(svcFB as URL) is used to check wether the Facebook app is installed.